# how to use uniq command on the first two field

Tags: linux, sorting, uniq

here's the full pipeline im developing so far:

```
cut -d ";" -f 1,2,3,5 merge_of_raw_data.csv | sort -t";" -k4 -r | cut -d ";" -f 1-3 | uniq
```

so the last cut command will give something like that:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
1 2 3
1 2 5
1 3 3
```

but then i would like to keep only the uniq lines based on the first two field

using:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2 --unique
```

doesn't solve what i want since i need to keep the first occurrence has its already sorted by date.

the expected output for this example would be:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
1 3 3
```

Comment: well i think the sort --unique does the trick actually... made a few tests since i posted the question, and looks like the first occurrence is kept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input after the last cut is producing your expected output with:

```
cat input.txt | sort -k1,1 -k2,2 --unique
```

However, the order is different than your expected output:

```
1 2 3
1 3 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
```

The output is sorted based on the k1, then k2 columns.